# How to find maximum distance apart of values within a variable

Tags: stata

I create a working example dataset:

```
input ///
group value
1    3
1    2
1    3 
2    4
2    6
2    7 
3    4
3    4 
3    4
3    4
4    17
4    2
5    3
5    5
5    12
end
```

My goal is to figure out the maximum distance between incremental `value`s within `group`. For `group 2`, this would be `2`, because the next highest value after `4` is `6`. Note that the only `value` relevant to `4` is `6`, not `7`, because `7` is not the next highest value after `4`. The result for group `3` is `0` because there is only one value in group `3`. There will only be one result per `group`.

What I want to get:

```
input ///
group value result
1    3    1
1    2    1
1    3    1
2    4    2
2    6    2
2    7    2
3    4    0
3    4    0
3    4    0
3    4    0
4    17   15
4    2    15
5    3    7
5    5    7
5    12   7
end
```

The order is not important, so the order just above can change with no problem.

Any tips?

Comment: Reading in values as `str5` makes no sense as you intend to make subtractions. I've edited that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have figured it out:

```
bys group (value): gen d = value[_n+1] - value[_n]
bys group: egen result = max(d)
drop d
```

Comment: `value[_n]` can be written simply as `value`.